# Boost Numeric Constants Pros

Tags: c++, boost, constants, cmath

What do I gain (I guess in terms of type safety, performance and accuracy) by using Boost Numeric Constants, such as `pi<T>`, defined in `<boost/math/constants/constants.hpp>` instead of including `<cmath>` and instead using `M_PI`, other than a warmer computer during compilation :)?

Comment: `M_PI` is not standard and might as well not be in `<cmath>` at all.

Comment: You get type safety.

Answer (score 2):

Type saftey and greater precision.

"All the constants are accurate to at least the 34 decimal digits required for 128-bit long doubles, and most are accurate to 100 digits or more when used with a suitable arbitrary precision type."

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/math/constants/constants.hpp